# How to do segmentation of full raster image using OrfeoToolBox

Tags: qgis-2, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

I want to do segmentation of raster image using OTB segmentation(mean-shift). But it is generating the ouput for only selected region or part of the raster image. So if i want to do the segmentation of full raster image using mean shift how can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

2 solutions:

- approximate vector results of the mean-shift on full image using the Segmentation application with the vector mode:

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu130.html#x166-9550005.9.8

- Or you can produce an exact segmentation (raster) of the full image following the LSMS workflow which require to use 3 different applications in  a row:

https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/CookBook/CookBooksu42.html#x64-920004.3.3

I advise to try the 2nd solution.